# VS2013 - Web Essentials - "Update All Bundles" does not work

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, bundling-and-minification, web-essentials

In visual studio 2013 (update 2 **or** 3) there is a web essentials menu option.
When choosing "update all bundles" from this menu, nothing happens.

Current work around, when i want my javascript to re-bundle i have to edit/save one of the js files.

Anyone know if there's a fix for this, or something i'm just not thinking of?

Comment: What's with the downvotes people? I have the same issue. Running VS13 and WE13 U2 (2.2).

Answer (score 1):

Just went through a similar problem and found that a developer had checked in an updated .bundle file with the XML formatted differently (they were using 2013).  The new structure didn't have an output attribute and I had the same problem as the one you describe.

I put the xml back to how it was and it now builds with 2012 again, I'll try 2013 next.

Comment: i had a similar problem as well, still no 2013 solution here, but at least the work around is sufficient for now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem under Visual Studio 2012. The command was there, but Update all bundles wouldn't work, same on build. 
Got the source code, debugged and found out that at least for the version I have (3.8) anything under **~/App_Data** folder is **skipped**. 
So I moved my bundles and files and it works like a charm now.